# character '@' in comment: procedure is not compiling

Tags: comments, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anybody explain to me, why this syntax is not working at all, when I try to compile it in a SQL Developer worksheet? It seems as the '@' char is kind of preprocessed by th SQL Developer, but I did not find any explanations, why what is happening here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST
IS
/*
@ example
*/
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test @ Procedure');
END;

/
```

this works fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST
IS
/*
 -  example
*/
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test @ Procedure');
END;
/
```

SQL Developer Version 17.2.0.188 
Oracle Database 12c

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say it's not working, can you show the error that SQL Developer is giving you?

It could be a SQL Developer bug. If I try the same code in version 18.3, it compiles just fine.

[image]

Comment: there is not even an error output. Literally nothing happens.

Comment: if I _set define off; _ before compiling it, I get an error output: Error starting at line : 122 in command - */ Error report - Unknown Command SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP 
and to leave enter EXIT.
Test @ Procedure 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: what you see above is what happens for me with no additional work other than copy and pasting your code into the worksheet, and hitting F5...Control+Enter also worked

Comment: try with version 18.3